# Make filter to filter in a specific table only?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, powerbi-desktop, ssas-tabular

I have a **ClientType** dimension connected to **Date** dim. (**ClientType** table has columns: ClientNo, Year and Type)

In the pbix  I use a filter on: **Date dim, on year,** which correctly filters my fact in the visualizations… It also correctly filters the dimension for the selected year.

My issue is; that I want to use the same dimension value for both current year and LY measures:

```
Revenue YTD := CALCULATE([Revenue] , DATESYTD('Date'[Date] ,"31/05" ))

Revenue LYTD:=CALCULATE( [Revenue YTD],  SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date]))
```

This second measures: fetches data for last year, and is also trying to pick the dimension from last year (which I dont want!)… And I get the strange behavior where I can see the data but not in the dimension only in the total…

[image]